Symbol clashes (Error LNK2005 frexp already defined in libmmt.lib(frexp_iface_c99.obj)) with Intel icx compiler inside VS2022 in debug mode
I'm test building a C++20 project and I ran into a linker error after upgrading the Windows SDK from version 10.0.22621.0 to 10.0.26100.0.  The description given by the linker on VS2022 (17.10.3) is  "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error LNK2005 frexp already defined in libmmt.lib(frexp_iface_c99.obj) NNExtended D:\NNetworks\Fashion-MNIST\NNExtended\libucrtd.lib(frexp.obj) : 1 ".  When you examine the linker's log you can see
Found _decomp
Referenced in libucrtd.lib(fpexcept.obj)
Loaded libucrtd.lib(frexp.obj)
libucrtd.lib(frexp.obj) : : error LNK2005: frexp already defined in libmmt.lib(frexp_iface_c99.obj)

I think the error happens because the symbol frexp is defined in MSVC's static debug library libucrtd.lib and Intel's static library libmmt.lib!
frexp is indeed in the symbols exported by Intel's libmmt.lib
PS D:\> dumpbin.exe /symbols "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\lib\libmmt.lib" | Select-String "frexp"

008 00000000 SECT4 notype () External | __frexpq
frexpq.c
008 00000000 SECT4 notype () External | frexpf16
010 00000000 UNDEF notype External | frexpf
00B 00000000 SECT5 notype () External | __libm_frexpl_ex
frexpl.c
008 00000000 SECT4 notype () External | __libm_frexpf_ex
frexpf.c
008 00000000 SECT4 notype () External | __libm_frexp_e7
frexp_ct.c
00B 00000000 SECT5 notype () External | __libm_frexp_ex
frexp_gen.c
03C 00000000 UNDEF notype External | __libm_frexpl
050 00000000 SECT1C notype () External | __bwr_frexpf
0AE 00000000 UNDEF notype External | __libm_frexpf_ex
00B 00000000 SECT5 notype () External | __bwr_frexp
frexp_bwr.c
008 00000000 SECT4 notype () External | frexpl
010 00000000 UNDEF notype External | __libm_frexpl_ex
008 00000000 SECT4 notype () External | __libm_frexpl
010 00000000 UNDEF notype External | __libm_frexpl_ex
008 00000000 SECT4 notype () External | frexpf
00C 00000000 UNDEF notype External | __libm_frexpf_ex
008 00000000 SECT4 notype () External | __libm_frexpf
00C 00000000 UNDEF notype External | __libm_frexpf_ex
008 00000000 SECT4 notype () External | frexp
00C 00000000 UNDEF notype External | __libm_frexp_chosen_core_func_icx
008 00000000 SECT4 notype () Static | __libm_frexp_dispatch_table_icx_init_icx
00D 00000000 SECT5 notype () External | __libm_frexp
017 00000000 SECT6 notype Static | __libm_frexp_dispatch_table_icx
018 00000000 SECT2 notype External | __libm_frexp_chosen_core_func_icx
019 00000000 UNDEF notype External | __libm_frexp_ex
01A 00000000 UNDEF notype External | __libm_frexp_e7

and symbols exported by libucrtd.lib
PS D:\> dumpbin.exe /symbols "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.26100.0\ucrt\x64\libucrtd.lib" | Select-String "frexp"

11B 00000000 SECT59 notype External | ??_C@_05GKKHEGJL@frexp@ (`string')
04A 00000000 SECT19 notype () External | frexp
059 00000000 SECT1D notype Static | $unwind$frexp
05C 00000000 SECT1E notype Static | $pdata$frexp

I get no compilation errors with Visual C++ compiler! This happens only with Intel's C++ compiler (2024.2.0.491). The compiler flags in this configuration are
/MP /GS /TP /Wall /QxCOMMON-AVX512 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /guard:cf /Zi /Od /debug:full /Ob0 /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "__TEST__" /D "__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER=20240200" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /fp:except /Zc:forScope /std:c17 /GR- /arch:AVX512 /MTd /QaxCOMMON-AVX512 /std:c++20 /Fa".\bin\Test\" /EHa /nologo /Fo".\bin\Test\" /Qstd=c++2a /Ot 


and the linker options are
/OUT:".\bin\Test\NNExtended.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:".\bin\Test\NNExtended.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG:FULL /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:".\bin\Test\NNExtended.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ILK:".\bin\Test\NNExtended.ilk" /NOLOGO /VERBOSE /TLBID:1 


How do I solve this problem? I'd appreciate any help regarding this! Thank you!

Tried removing libucrtd.lib from the /DEFAULTLIBS linker flag but this spews a ton of unresolved external errors.
Tried using Visual C++, compilation works fine. The problem only occurs with Intel's ICX!
Linking succeeds with ICX when I opt for dynamic linking with /MDd but fails with static linking /MTd!
Intel oneAPI C/C++ compiler manual states Intel compilers use the same libmmt.lib for static linking in both debug and release configurations with /MT & /MTd. But provides two separate libmmd.lib and libmmdd.lib for /MD & /MDd configurations! (Page 382)

